# Additional attributes in a dropdown (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I am populating a dropdown by calling the function

```
    function createOption(dropdown, text, value, gid) {
      var x = document.createElement('option');
      x.value = value;
      x.text = text;
      x.setAttribute("gid",gid);
      dropdown.options.add(x);
    }
```

I want the dropdown to have an additional attribute 'id' so that at particular values of the id, an alert box pops up. Now I call another function to pop the alert box up.

```
function showPopUp(dropdown) {
  console.log("from Show Pop-up: " + dropdown.getAttribute("gid")); //PRINTS null
  if(dropdown.getAttribute("gid")==5){
        alert("Approval needed");
    }
}
```

I am unable to access the id value of the dropdown in another function.

Comment: `dropdown.id = "something"`? You'll need to be more specific regarding what you mean by "particular values of the id"...

Comment: I mean for each value populating the dropdown, there is an 'id' attached to it.. if id=5, there should be an alert box that pops up.

Comment: Are you looking for [`setAttribute()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) and [`getAttribute()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)?

Comment: There a reason you can't use `value`?

Comment: @ Mike McCaughan yes. the condition is not based on the value. Its based on another attribute, a group id.

Comment: @user5673235 You used `dropdown.getAttribute("gid")` but `gid` has been applied to the `option` elements inside the dropdown, not to the dropdown itself.

Comment: Thankyou @user2464424 .. saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) in javascript.
It sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

```html
<select id="mySelect">
</select>

<p>Click the button to create an OPTION element with an id.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
    x.value = "value";
    x.text = "text";
    x.setAttribute("data-id", "id");
    document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

**P.S** You can distinguish particular option on the basis of value also. No need to use id.

Comment: The literal `id` attribute has a special meaning in html-land. [Prepend `data-`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) to the attribute key to allow arbitrary attributes (turn it into `data-id`).